# Change the text of dojo dijit

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, esri

I've been looking and trying to change this dijit text for days now and nothing seems to working.  I want to change the initial display of the dijit from "Print" to "Export".  I've tried using jquery to call the dijit and change the text.  I've also tried.

dojo.byId("print_button").innerHTML = "EXPORT";
dijit.byId("print_button").attr("export")

and least a few other things but I can not change the initial words from print to export.  Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED!

("

```
        //creates the templates and the dijit
    function handlePrintInfo(resp) {
        var templates;

        templates = [{
            label: "Image",
            format: "png32", //PNG format only
            layout: "MAP_ONLY",
            exportOptions: {width:1920, height:1182, dpi:200},
            showAttribution: false
            }];

        //create  the print dijit
        app.printer = new esri.dijit.Print
        ({
          "map": map,
          "templates": templates,                          
          url: app.printUrl                           
        }, dojo.byId("print_button"));
        app.printer.startup();

        app.printer._printText = "";
        app.printer._printingText = "Exporting";
        app.printer._printoutText = "Open Image";            

    } //end handleprintinfo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the call to the esri.dijit.Print constructor, but **before** the call to app.printer.startup(), do this:

```
app.printer._printText = "EXPORT";
```

That does the trick, at least with version 3.6 of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. I don't know which version you're using, but give it a try.

P.S. I didn't find documentation on this. Firebug is my friend. :-)

Comment: thank you....now looking at it i had the app.printer._printText = "Export" after the start up which meant was to late to change it.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the label of the button?

```
dijit.byId('print_button').set('label', 'Export')?
```

Comment: yea I've tired that it didnt work also. Either I'm not doing it in the correct spot or something else is wrong and I'm just not seeing it because I'm to focused on this issue.